# hide  a uiview with animation in ios4.2

Tags: animation, xcode4, ios-4.2

I am new in ios development.Now,i am developing an Ipad application using ios 4.2 .This ipad application 
needs some animation ,that is hide a uiview  in button action with some animation(ie. hidding slowly).How to implement this animation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start, look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html